# Trouble sorted pages index google

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.9

I currently have the mageplaza layered navigation extension on my site in Magento 2.2.9 and I have a problem :

Google indexes all the filter pages. I blocked some of them via the robots.txt but certainly remains indexed but I don't know how the blocked ones because they have a different scheme : 
https://mysite/lang/category/104-251-82.html

I don't know hiw to block them in the robots.txt

Can you help me? Because these pages are indexed but are of no use to the users.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you are allowed to enable/disable the pages that you want to index by Google via the Admin panel. Check out this guide for more detailed information: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html

Besides, Google doesn't index all the pages they have some restricted numbers. Here you can also check the exact number for indexing your pages.

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-not-going-to-index-all-your-pages-29110.html